# SharePoint sites URL redirecting to AllItem.aspx (not to the desired URL) in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online, I have a weird issue.
I have two sites where site-A has some left Navigations created that should direct me to the document library of Site-B. I have given the correct (Site-B Document Lib URL as a link) to those navigations but IT WON'T DIRECT me to the right place. Rather it redirects me to the AllItems.aspx (of Site-B as below):

It takes me to this: (incorrect URL)

```
company.sharepoint.com/sites/mysiteB/Shared%Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

Where I have given it this URL: (correct one)

```
company.sharepoint.com/sites/mysiteB/Shared%Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=sites/mysiteB/Shared%Documents/folders/myfolder1
```

It gets interesting (and weird) when I try to open those navigations as shown in image below, **IT WORKS TOTALLY FINE.**

[image: Navigation Options]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Why SharePoint is dropping your query string parameters

When the Publishing feature is activated on the site, SharePoint automatically trims off the query string parameters.

This is presumably because it's doing some extra work behind the scenes to monitor the links and keep them up to date when the page that's being linked to is renamed or deleted.

Interestingly, if you link to a location on a different site, or outside of SharePoint entirely, it'll keep the query string parameters. It's only links within the current site where it'll snip them off.

## Potential Solutions

### 1. Disable Publishing on the site

You may be able to work around this problem by [disabling the publishing feature](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SharePoint/en-US/d9647c30-40c8-4acc-94c7-5d77b530a5c5/sharepoint-2016-removing-querystring-parameters-in-native-site-navigation-menu?forum=sharepointdevelopment).

The downside to this is that you'd lose all the benefits of the publishing feature, so only go this route if you aren't taking advantage of the publishing framework.

### 2. Hack the link with JavaScript injection

One solution I've seen is to [inject JavaScript](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/39e66209-c42c-4ed0-b016-379a71be29d6/add-query-string-parameter-to-quick-launch-navigation-items?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) onto each page where the link appears; the JavaScript would find the link and append the query string parameters for you.

That's rather hokey, though.

### 3. Tell SharePoint to behave itself using code

One way to resolve it is to tell SharePoint what you want the query string parameter to be, or tell it that this link is external and therefore shouldn't be treated differently. Unfortunately it only lets you do this [programmatically](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62565/add-quicklaunch-link-with-querystring-parameter-programatically); there is no user interface for adding query string parameters or marking a link as external, and the navigation menu provided by the publishing infrastructure feature doesn't cut it.

### 4. Link to a redirect page instead

One last potential workaround that might be simplest would be to create a redirect page.

This page could have some JavaScript on it that sends you to the correct page with the query string parameter appended to the URL. You can link to the redirect page in your left nav instead of linking directly to the page with the query string parameters.

```
<script> 
window.location.href = "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/mysiteB/Shared%Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=sites/mysiteB/Shared%Documents/folders/myfolder1"; 
</script>
```

If JavaScript is too intimidating or dangerous for your scenario, the page could also just contain some explanatory text and a clickable link instead of an automatic redirect. The users can click that link to get to the page with the proper query string parameters appended to the URL.

Comment: Yep, I had hard time figuring out the root cause of the problem. For the time being, I went into individual documents and copied the link from COPY LINK tab and replaced it the initial URL(Detailed URL). And it magically solved my problem. I will look/test into disabling publishing feature to learn more about it. Thank you for your time and assistance. :)